# Finder Tags not working for any SMB files

Tags: finder, mojave, finder-tag

I'm having an issue with Finder Tags and SMB share? I can tag a file with a colour. But when I go view in the tags it does not show for any SMB shared files? I have tried everything. Finder is creating a DS file. I have opened up the permissions etc. Just refuses to show the coloured tags? Anyone know why? If this does work for you please could you share you config.

Answer (score -1):

I made an alias and then tag the alias.